# Xpath starts-with, ends-with validation

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, xpath, microsoft-test-manager

I am doing automation in MTM.

UI:

As Low As: $12,983.30  $108.19  120  5.43%

1. I need to validate that number 12,983.30  starts with $
2. I need to validate that number 5.43 ends with %

Code:
[for 1st test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/07Tt8.png)

So I was able to validate that element $12,983.30 exist and has $:

```
"xpath" "//*[+id='-student-loan-finder-form']/div/div[17]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2][text()[contains(., '$')]]" "Total Cost has $" "true"
```

But I wasn't successful to validate that the number starts with $:

```
"xpath" "//*[+id='-student-loan-finder-form']/div/div[17]/div[2]/div[2]/div[2][text()[starts-with(., '$')]]" "Total Cost starts with $" "true"
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: The $ isn't the first character. You are pulling the `DIV` which starts with "Total Cost:..." so "T" is the first character and that's what is compared when considering `starts-with()`.

Comment: <div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 totalCostLow">
<span class="mobile-label">Total Cost: </span>
 $12,983.30
</div>

Comment: So how can I confirm that $ goes before the digits?

Answer (score 0):

The $ isn't the first character. You are pulling the DIV which starts with "Total Cost:..." so "T" is the first character and that's what is compared when considering `starts-with()`.

There are any number of ways to do this. Probably the simplest way is to split the returned text by ":" and then `Trim()` and look at the 2nd part.

Given the HTML you posted

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-sm-12 totalCostLow">
    <span class="mobile-label">Total Cost: </span>
    $12,983.30
</div>
```

getting the text from the outer `DIV` would return something like (whitespace may differ)

```
"Total Cost:  $12,983.30 "
```

You can split that string using ":"

```
"Total Cost", "  $12,983.30 "
```

grab the second string and `Trim()` it

```
"$12,983.30"
```

and then make sure the first character is "$"

That code would look something like

```
string priceString = <get the price string>; // e.g. "Total Cost:  $12,983.30 "
string price = priceString .Split(':')[1].Trim();
```

Now you can validate that `price` starts with a "$".